# java protected why is this working through non-inheritance?

Tags: java, protected

I'm obviously missing the obvious in this but given:

```
package a;
public class Class1 {
    protected int a=1;
}

package b;
import a.*;

public class Class2 extends Class1 {
    Class2() {
        Class1 c1=new Class1();
        Class2 c2=new Class2();
        System.out.println(a);     //1
        System.out.println(c1.a);  //2
        System.out.println(c2.a);  //3
    }
}
```

I know //1 is fine due to being used through inheritance and //2 fails because it's not being access through inheritance, but why is //3 ok too? I thought variable a was being accessed through a new object and a resides in Class1?

Thanks.

Comment: not relevant to the actual question, but calling this constructor will cause a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I put it in main but then took it out to save on the number of lines of code and to allow me to put in line //1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are manipulating an object inside its class, you have full access to all his attributes, including the private ones. As `c2` is a instance of `Class2` and you are manipulating it inside the `Class2` code, you can see the protected attribute.

Comment: Thanks. So assuming no data hiding Class2 inherits all of Class1 so 'a' becomes part of Class2 as a protected member effectively.

Comment: `including the private ones.` -> Sorry??

Comment: @RohitJain If you have a class called `Test` and you have a attribute declared `private int abc;` you can declare a variable `Test t = new Test();` and do something like `t.abc = 123;` if you are inside the class `Test`

Comment: @DanielPereira. You don't mean - `from anywhere`, do you? And if not, then your answer is not very clear about that.

Answer (score 4):

Since any object of `Class2` is-a `Class1`, it can access all of `Class 1`'s member variables with scopes `default`, `protected` and `public`.

Besides, trying to understand scope and inheritance rules through working with objects that are of the class you are using to play with scopes/inhertiance is not a good idea, since it works in a different way than through a third-party (which is the most common use.)

For instance, this is allowed:

```
public class Something {
   private int something;

   public int stealSomething(final Something otherthing) {
       return otherthing.something;
   }
}
```

Try making a third class, that is not in the hierarchy of the classes you are using to test.

Comment: Cheers. I think this stems from normally using base classes as the reference type when creating subclasses and observing the error.

Answer (score 3):

> why is //3 ok too?

And why shouldn't it be ok? Given that `Class2` is the subclass of `Class1`, so a `protected` fields of `Class1` are accessible through the instance of `Class2`. And that is what you are doing here. `c2` is an instance of `Class2`, and `a` field is visible for it.

**NOTE:** A *protected member* is accessible to *any direct subclass*, whether in same package or in different package.

> I thought variable a was being accessed through a new object

Yeah, that's true.

> and a resides in Class1?

That really doesn't matter here. As far as `a` is accessible to `Class2` instance, it is valid.

And just FYI, your code will die of `StackOverflowError`. You need to take care of it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I put it in main but then took it out to save on the number of lines of code and to allow me to put in line //1 :) this is just testing code not a real bit of code

Comment: @Neil. Ok. Then it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the problem.

Class1 has a variable named 'a'.  Since it is 'protected', that variable is visible within any object of Class1 and any object of a class extending Class1.

If 'a' were private, then it would not be visible this way in objects of classes extending Class1.

Comment: "Class2 extends Class1" - it IS a subclass, different package does not matter here.